# phpmailer send separate pages

Tags: php, phpmailer

How would I go about sending multiple pages through email?  For instance, I want to send an email that includes a cover page, and after the user scrolls down, a second page with data.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "page" in an email?

Comment: A responsive document opened by an email program that fits to the height, width specifications of said email program.  There will be a link in the bottom left/right that says"next page" that should traverse to an anchor that will fill another page

Comment: I've been building a lot of HTML-emails and one thing I can say is that you more or less need to code like it is 1999 with tables and inline HTML-styling. Many clients won't even accept CSS. In my experience, even if you make it work in one client... it most definitly won't work in others.

Comment: I was afraid that I would get that answer.... :D

Comment: I agree with Magnus. One alternative is to generate a PDF and send it as attachment to your e-mail (this can all be done in PHP). Then you have full control over your pages. Second alternative is to send a link to a webpage - then you have better control over your layout.

Comment: The PDF way seems like the ideal way of going, how would i separate pages with something that converts my document to PDF?

Comment: Look at [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org) for generating PDFs, but before you do, it's worth knowing that anchors (intra-page links) work quite well in many email clients, and that may give something close enough to what you want. You can't really match height in an email, but it's easy to make width responsive. Ultimately, keep it simple. Bear in mind that while PDFs will break your layout into pages, there's no guarantee it will be displayed in an email client anyway, and it won't solve the height issue.